# Find the positive value of $k$ such that the equation $ke^x - x = 0$ has exactly one real solution.

Tags: exponential-function

The positive value of $k$ for which the equation $ke^x - x = 0$ has only one root.

The given equation holds true only if $k\in(0,1)$ but I couldn't get anything further than this. The correct answer for this is $k=\frac1e$.

Comment: Is your equation $ke^{x}=0$?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the question correctly? If $k>0$, then $k e^x > 0$ has no roots!

Comment: sorry! my mistake. i edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the global minimum minimum by solving 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (k\exp(x)-x)=0$$
$$k\exp(x)-1=0$$
$$\exp(x)=1/k$$
$$x=\ln(1/k)$$
So the value at the minimum is
$$k\exp(\ln(1/k))-\ln(1/k)=1-\ln(1/k)$$
There will be only one root when the global minimum $=0$:
$$1-\ln(1/k)=0$$
Solve for k.

Comment: also if i have to solve the following equation for 2 distinct roots, i'll have to make the minimum value negative. right?

Comment: yes. To complete the argument, note that the function is positive in both the $x\rightarrow +\infty$ and the $x\rightarrow +\infty$ limits, so the [Intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) guarantees the existence of roots.